# Book about .Net Compact Framework development

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I'm searching for a book about developing with .Net Compact Framework. Does anybody have any hints?

Thanks. Yours,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following books will be more than enough to suit your needs:

- [Microsoft® Mobile Development Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623589)
- [.NET Compact Framework Programming with C# (Microsoft .NET Development Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321174038)
- [Microsoft .NET Compact Framework (Core Reference)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617252)

Answer (score 2):

This [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623589) "Microsoft® Mobile Development Handbook " is certainly one of the best.

Some of the authors are also involved with the open source OpenNETCF product so they absolutely know what they are talking about.